# MysqldResource isn't working with MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, mysql, macos-catalina

Since upgrading my os to Mac Catalina, 
I'm getting the following error when trying to run the following:

```
    MysqldResource mysqldResource = new MysqldResource(uri); // Uri - temp db dir
            mysqldResource.start("embedded-mysqld-thread-" + System.currentTimeMillis(), databaseOptions);
```

Looks like the source of the problem is with the dependency "mysql-connector-mxj-db-files" having binary files in 32bit format, while catalina stopped supporting it.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    Exception in thread "embedded-mysqld-thread-1574931580040" com.mysql.management.util.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/private/var/folders/l5/4ywgvbbj1kvgvrwxzp6dz82c0000gn/T/test_db_24166997810717/bin/mysqld": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
        at com.mysql.management.util.Exceptions.toRuntime(Exceptions.java:55)
        at com.mysql.management.util.Exceptions$Block.exec(Exceptions.java:89)
        at com.mysql.management.util.RuntimeI$Default.exec(RuntimeI.java:180)
        at com.mysql.management.util.Shell$Default.run(Shell.java:140)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/private/var/folders/l5/4ywgvbbj1kvgvrwxzp6dz82c0000gn/T/test_db_24166997810717/bin/mysqld": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at com.mysql.management.util.RuntimeI$Default$1.inner(RuntimeI.java:177)
        at com.mysql.management.util.Exceptions$Block.exec(Exceptions.java:86)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 6 more
```

Does anyone know of an alternative to mysql-connector-java or knows of a way to run the existing dependency on Mac OS Catalina?

Comment: Search in google for 'mac catalina bad cpu type' for several clues on trying to run 32 bit data on 64 bit equipment.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same issue on MacOS Catalina, you can follow the README.md in my repo (https://github.com/pengyue/mysql-connector-mxj-mac-os-catalina), which has the 64 bits executables for MacOS Catalina, and this improved connector works on Catalina.

To explain what I have done:

- Download the 64 bits executables from MySQL to the folder `5-5-9`
- Add the platform mapping for 64 bits MacOS in `platform-map.properties`
- Create a jar by using `jar cvf mysql-connector-mxj-db-files-5.0.12.jar .`
- Replace the jar in your mvn settings folder `~/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-mxj-db-files/5.0.12/` with the jar you just created.

This solution works fine for my projects, Unfortunately I could not find a github for the mysql-connector-mxj, as it is deprecated and not maintainable anymore.

The other option is to use wix-embedded-mysql(https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql) instead of mysql-connector-mxj, but this probably requires some code changes in your projects.